# Using ViewGroup and View on Android draw and make buttons using canvas

Tags: android, view, android-canvas, android-button, viewgroup

I'm trying to make my own custom view, currently all it does is draw an image on a specific x and y coordinate and then draws the similar images repeatedly on different locations.

I want to be able to create a button on each instance of the image that is drawn. if one image is clicked it will have cause something different to happen depending on which image is chosen.

How can I implement this?

would I have to create a different view for each image/button combination and then set an onClick event?

---

Let me try to be a little more clear
I'm trying to make a map using hexagon (different types of terrains for different players)
I've figured out how to get them to draw ([see here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/115220963240687480537/albums/5709536986035019953/5717575656760639138) - they will have a border to show what terrain is owned by whom)

I just made a custom view class and had the hexagons drawn using a Canvas; however, I'm not sure how to be able to make the hexagons into buttons so that I can differentiate between which hexagon was chosen and how it should react to the opponents spot.

I was thinking of making a ViewGroup called Terrain to contain the Nodes(hexagons) that belong to the player and have a group of Node Views that only draw the hexagon where it should be located.

the question is can i make each node or the entire viewGroup into a button (or do an onTouch ) if a certain hexagon is pressed?

Comment: I've manually kept track of image locations, and check for a click within the image boundary. But I guess you're looking for a more automated approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help!

I figured out what I needed to do.
I have a NodeView class and in my GameActivity class, I'm using a relative layout and setting the layout parameters of where I wanted things positioned

```
    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(95,95);
    params.leftMargin = 10;
    params.topMargin = 10;


    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(95,95);
    params.leftMargin = 10+95*x;
    params.topMargin = 81+(71*y);
    rl.addView(new NodeView (this,0,0,1,1), params);
```

This helped me add things where I needed them and now all I'm trying to figure out how to scroll around the territories on both the x and y axis (I tried ScrollView but that only allows me to scroll on the y-axis, I'm looking into it though)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, you should do :

- One template my_pictures.xml which is a simple button.
- Then you create a custom adapter which as a function for each kind of image you wanna create. By this, I mean that you will have to change the background value of your button depending on what you need it to be. Then you do a `notifyDataSetChanged()`; to refresh the container with the new button.
- For the Listener, you just have to add it either in your activity or your adapter when you create your buttonImages, I don't know what's better.